rope_scaling error | Llama-3.1-70B | Not working even after transformers update
I am just downloading 4bit quantised Llama-3.1-70B
nf4_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
load_in_4bit=True,
bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
“meta-llama/Llama-3.1-70B”,
trust_remote_code=True,
use_safetensors=True,
token=HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN,
device_map="auto",
quantization_config=nf4_config
)

but still getting this error
ValueError: rope_scaling must be a dictionary with with two 
fields, type and factor, got {'factor': 8.0, 'low_freq_factor': 
1.0, 'high_freq_factor': 4.0, 'original_max_position_embeddings': 
8192, 'rope_type': 'llama3'}

Based on llama/huggingface documentations, I tried to update tranformers, vllms, python etc but nothing working for me, one catch might be I am using AWS G5.12Xlarge/A10 instances which has 96GiB GPU, do I need at least A100 even for downloading ?
these are the details
Python: 3.8.8
OS:

Ubuntu version =Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Kernal : 5.15.0-1068-aws

GPU :

NVIDIA-SMI 535.183.01
Driver Version: 535.183.01
CUDA Version: 12.2
4*NVIDIA A10G => 96GiB GPU

Packages

vllm : 0.5.5
transformers : 4.45.1

I tried all answer here but nothing working : https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct/discussions/15
any suggestion ?
